# How to convert a list of strings to data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to convert a list of strings to a data frame.
Given structure:

```
lst <- list(NULL, "PSYC", c("PSYC", "PHIL"), "PHIL")
```

I want to produce a dataframe of

```
      Index     major_cd
       1            NULL
       2            PSYC
       3            PSYC
       3            PHIL
       4            PHIL
```

Note how the 3rd item in list turned into 2 rows of the data frame.

Comment: You may need to replace the `NULL` with a character 'NULL' or so to get the desired output

Comment: Taking akruns comment in account, you could also do something ugly like `cbind.data.frame(Index = rep(seq(length(l)), lapply(l, length)),  major_cd = unlist(l))` with base R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could replace the NULL elements in the 'lst' with 'NA' or "NULL" and use `unnest` from `tidyr` after setting the names of the 'lst'

```
lst[sapply(lst, is.null)] <- NA
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments, setting to `"NULL"` instead of `NA` will give the expected output as showed

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)), Index)
#  Index    x
#1     1 <NA>
#2     2 PSYC
#3     3 PSYC
#4     3 PHIL
#5     4 PHIL
```

Comment: Or in base R, `stack(setNames(lapply(lst, function(x) replace(x, is.null(x), NA)), seq_along(lst)))`.